# Visual Studio load testing, is it real-world?

Tags: visual-studio, load-testing

Is it even possible to fake the traffic, considering your network connection will have a bandwidth limit? If I create a test for 1000 users, visiting 3 pages a second, will the results really represent this scenario if done in real life (not simulation)?

Should I create an executable to perform the load test, and run it from separate network connections?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a concern that the network bandwidth limit of the test machine will invalidate the accuracy of the test. To determine if your concern is legit, perform the following rough assessment. Let say your three pages have sizes 20k, 40k and 60k respectively. To load test them  you would need to generate the following maximum bandwidth:

1000x (20k+40k+60k)= 120Mbps

Make an adjustment for compression if you use it. Factor in the requests sizes if they are significant. If you test with browser caching emulation enabled, increase the size of the first requests by the size of static resources. Then compare the maximum bandwidth with your network adapter bandwidth. If it is 100 Mbps, then the network adapter will be a bottleneck. If it is 1 Gps or more, then the network adapter will not be a bottleneck.

Alternatively, skip calculations and just run the test. On the bandwidth graph in VSTS find the max value. If it is by far smaller than your network adapter limit, then you can run this test from one machine.
Keep in mind that requesting 1000 x 3 pages per second does not guarantee that you will receive responses from 1000 X 3 pages per second due to the server speed limit.